# Magento Products create menu sub selections

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a Category (Test-Category) I have 3 products inside of it. (Magento 1.9.3.3)

This test category is included in my main menu. Right now I have that Category page displaying its 3 products.

I would like to have those products show as items in the menu under this category.

```
Test-Category
--Product 1
--Product 2
--Product 3
```

Those items would link directly to the product pages.

I have managed to do this by creating categorys for each product, but then the link displays as a category page with 1 product in it. Maybe it's easier to redirect what this "category page" displays?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured this out by adding a custom URL to the product category page that is the product URL